# Visualizing a system of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have the following system of differential equations:

```
x'[t] == x[t] - x[t] y[t]
y'[t] == x[t] y[t] - y[t]
```

I use this Wolfram Mathematica code:

```
Clear[x, s, y, t]

sol = 
  NDSolveValue[
    {x'[t] == x[t] - y[t]*x[t], y'[t] == y[t]*x[t] - y[t], 
     x[0] == 100, y[0] == 100}, 
    {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}]

Plot[sol, {x, 0, 90}]
```

I get this output:

[image]

I tried using DSolve instead of NDSolveValue but I don't get any output at all.

Is there a way to visualize these two equations on the same graph? If it is possible, how should I change my code?

Thank you!

Comment: `Plot[{sol[[1]][t], sol[[2]][t]}, {t, 0, 90},
 PlotLegends -> {x[t], y[t]}]` **or** `Plot[Evaluate[#[t] & /@ sol], {t, 0, 90},
 PlotLegends -> {x[t], y[t]}]`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `sol` with `{xF, yF}` and then write you plot like this:

```
Plot[{xF[t], yF[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, PlotLegends -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}]
```

Then you will get

[image: plot]